# JSONObject exceptions

Tags: java, json, jsp

I am using a JSON array to process data back n forth between layers. I have been getting an exception on JSONObject. Could you please guide me towards the correct debug path for this issue? 
**First approach:**

```
for( Object obj : salesDataArray )
{
 JSONObject salesData = (JSONObject) obj;
```

Exception I am getting:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String incompatible with net.sf.json.JSONObject
```

**Second approach:**

```
for( Object obj : salesDataArray )
{
JSONObject salesData = JSONObject.fromObject(obj);
```

Exception I am getting:

```
net.sf.json.JSONException: Unquotted string 'undefined'
```

Comment: Have you tried: `String salesData = (String) obj;`? And what is the result of `obj.getClass()`?

Comment: What class is obj of? If it's a string, what are its contents?

Comment: Hi thkala, class is JSONObject. <br/> OBJECT CLASS NAME >>>>:class net.sf.json.JSONObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.println((String) obj);
```

Sounds like you don't have valid JSON data in there in the first place if you have 'undefined' in it.  Javascript undefined is like 'null' in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Your `salesDataArray` is an array of `String` objects, not `JSONObject` objects.  Where is this being populated?  Best best is to print out the values of the `salesDataArray` and find out what the strings are, and look upstream for the reason that they are set that way.

Also, consider using generics to type your `salesDataArray`, like

```
List<JSONObject> salesDataArray = ....  // get the sales data from somewhere
```

Comment: Hi Richard, all the data comes from the front end tier.

Comment: Richard, salesDataArray is a JSONArray

Comment: From the documentation (http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) it's not immediately obvious that the elements of a JSONArray are necessarily JSONObjects (see, for example, the return type on get()).  I guess I'd try an old fashioned for(int i = 0; i < salesDataArray.length; i++) loop and do a salesDataArray.getJSONObject(i) and see what happens.